# How to authorize user who logged in using external login in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity-2

**Introduction**
I am working with authorization in application, registered users are authorized on role based for some actions/controllers i.e

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Developer,Admin,User")]
```

My question is, What if a user is logged in using external login method like facebook or google, how to authorize him.

What should be or can be done to achieve this, if someone know about that then please do help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just add them to a role in the external login callback method

Comment: @RachitGupta thanks for reply, Can you please make it in an answer?

Comment: check my answer below. Hope that it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
          var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, DisplayName=model.Displayname };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "ExternalUser");// This is the important line

                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }

    }
```

Whenever the user logs in via an external service, he is automatically mapped to the role "External user". Now you can authorize it like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Externaluser")]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you log them in in the 'proper' way, all of the roles stuff works as expected, your `[Authorize(Roles = "Developer,Admin,User"]` attribute will work as expected out of the box.

The best advice that I can give on this one, is to open Visual Studio, create a new ASP.NET MVC website and choose individual user accounts.  The code that is created has a full implementation that encompasses the external logins functionality (Facebook, Twitter etc.).

You should replicate the way that it is written in the template/example within your own code base.

Comment: Thanks for help, Adding external login user role solved the problem

Comment: Glad to have helped.